# Have we ever encountered any Betazoid word besides "Imzadi"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, languages, betazoid

Like the question says.   We know the word *Imzadi* meaning something like *Beloved*.

But have we ever encountered any other word?

(Is it possible it's literally the least-developed (>0) language from a commonly recurring species?)

Comment: Canon or non canon? I know for sure there are some in non canon fiction works.

Comment: The name of the "Sacred Chalice of Rixx" would seem to indicate that "Rixx" is a Betazoid word.  Probably a proper noun.

Comment: @JohnP, canon, of course.   Non-canon is worthless.   It would be okay as incidentally trivia, I guess.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Betazed

Comment: Just FYI, Rixx is "Rick's" as in Rick Berman.

Comment: Note also that their entire 'home' language is telepathic.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Most of the "words" on that page are proper nouns. I don't know if that's particularly useful.

Comment: I believe we hear the Betazed term for incorrigible shagger — “Riker” — several times in the show.

Comment: It strikes me that the Betazoids are perhaps the most under-utilized and ill-planned characters in all of Star Trek.  At an official level, it would be logical for their presence to be mandated at most negotiations, in order to ensure good faith, as in *Babylon 5*. At a social level, members of a telepathic species would likely be feared by many, again as in *B5*.  Finally, they would be useful for a number of covert operations, again as in *B5*.  On the whole, I find the idea of telepaths in Star Trek to be one of the most poorly developed points.

Comment: @Praxis:   Given the choice I would wipe out all psy type crap from my scifi completely.   No telepathy.   No thought-and-time-and-space garbage.  The electrical patterns in my brain probably cannot exist outside it and cannot be read at a distance without high-res probably destructive scanning.   And even if possible, my brain is made of meat so it can't cause interactions at a distance by itself.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Speak for yourself.  My mind is stainless steel.

Answer (score 3):

## No, we do not

A thorough search of all Star Trek franchise television and film scripts shows that no other Betazoid word is uttered on screen (other than likely proper nouns such as "Rixx").

There may be plenty of instances in EU materials — such as the Peter David novel *Imzadi* or licensed video games — but these are non-canon at best.

Note that the Klingon, Vulcan, and Romulan languages were developed partly due to a desire by fans to *converse in these languages* (Klingon being the most developed, due to the efforts of linguist Marc Okrand at the time of *STIII*).  I doubt there is much desire by anyone to converse in Betazoid.  Their language has never been a plot point either — the focus being on their ability to communicate *without* speaking.

Comment: It makes my day when you make an appearance.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Awww.

Answer (score -1):

[The d20 wiki](http://startrekd20.wikia.com/wiki/Betazoids) lists some Betazoid names, which have meanings, which may come close to your answer:

Female Names: 
Deanna- Means: Nature's Beauty

Ania- Means: Spring blossom

Kestra- Means: Falling Leaves

Lwaxanna-Timeless beauty

Dalera- Means: Rainbow
Gloranna - Means: Glorious Beauty

Male Names:

Algar - Means: Wise

Jensar - Means: Joy

Nikael - Means: Lucky

Kalos - Means: Envied

Rennan - Means: Gentle

Kalos - Means: Envied

Comment: Are the Star Trek RPG's considered canon? d20 is a RPG oriented site.

Comment: As they are names used on the show, and a couple from the novels, I deemed it appropriate.  If I spend more time on it, I might be able to find similar references on more show-connected sources.  But these are the only "words" I've found, and thought they'd add to the conversation.

Comment: Even if the names are used on the show, their *meanings* are decidedly non-canon. And without that these are just names, which I don't think count as "words."

Comment: It's obvious that we know there are Betazoid names.  But they can't possibly count in canon unless a meaning is assigned in canon.  In addition, it occurs to me,  I could translate *snookums* or some other English term of endearment as *beloved* too, I suppose, so this actually suggests the possibility the *imzadi* isn't actually a meaningful Betazoid word either!

Answer (score -2):

In TNG S3E2 "[The Ensigns of Command](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ensigns_of_Command_(episode))" Troi uses the word "S'smarith" when discussing the difficulties of learning the Sheliak language:

> TROI: Attempted and failed. Actually, the fact that any alien race communicates with another is quite remarkable. We are stranded on a planet. We have no language in common, but I want to teach you mine. (she hold up his cup of tea) **S'smarith. What did I just say?** 
>   PICARD: Cup? Glass? 
>   TROI: Are you sure? I may have meant liquid, clear, brown, hot. **We conceptualise the universe in relatively the same way.** 
>   PICARD: Point taken.

Technically we don't know that this word is Betazoid, or that is necessarily means "cup" as is implied, but consider that Troi says "we conceptualise the universe in relatively the same way", it seems logical that:

- The word S'smarith is from a language through which she conceptualizes the universe, i.e. her native language.
- It means what Picard presumes it to mean based on how he conceptualizes the universe, i.e., 'cup.'

Comment: This is a stretch to me. I always got the impression that she invented the word to illustrate her point. Also, there's a really good chance Picard is able to recognize some basic words in Betazoid since he essentially lives onboard with at least one person who's fluent and a second person who is, if not fluent, at least familiar with the language, not to mention having access to a massive computing system that would also supply information on the Betazoid language. In order for Troi to drive home her point, she'd need a word that Picard would not recognize at all.